# .Net DataTable column export

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, split, append

Im looking to get a column and all its row data from a DataTable object then create a new column in another data table and append it with the new column and its rows. The issue I keep encountering is the row data will come out, as will the column names, but all of the rows are appended to the same column, I'm sure im missing something obvious, infact I know I am! Any help is greatly appriciated.

```
    void GetColumns()
    {
        // add the columns to the new datatable
        foreach (int i in mapValues)
        {
            SplitData.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        // map values contains the index numbers of my target columns
        foreach (int x in mapValues)
        {

            foreach (DataRow row in OrigData.Rows)
            {
                SplitData.Rows.Add(row[mapValues[LocalIndex]]);
            }

            LocalIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post (an outline of) your code.

Comment: This is where the issue is, I am aware that I need to somehow iterate through the columns along with the rows, although I have not seen a clear way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataRow.Add overload that you are using is the params one, so you are just putting your orig column data in the first column of the new DataTable.

You probably want something like:

```
DataRow newRow = SplitData.NewRow(); // gets a new blank row with the right schema
newRow[x.ToString()] = row[mapValues[LocalIndex]; // sets the column (that you created before) to the orig data
SplitData.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

as the core of your second for loop. You might as well do it in one loop too.

Comment: Cheers buddy I knew it was something simple

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer was totally right and I learned something from it, it turns out the DataTable.ImportRow method is exactly what I want for my needs, so just for future reference for anyone who might stumble upon this.